# Reverse geocoding with gadm database in r language

Tags: r, overlay, raster, reverse-geocoding

I have 6000 object with only lng and lat.
Using GADM dataset for Poland i can find where the point is.
Here i have LargeSpdataframe with boundries of
voivoships

```
library(raster)

voiv<-getData("GADM", country = "PL", level = 1)
```

counities

```
county<-getData("GADM", country = "PL", level = 2)
```

and on level down, more dedailed breakdown

```
gm<-getData("GADM", country = "PL", level = 3)
```

I want to find where the points are, like this.( its only eg.)

```
lng      lat      voiv   county     gm

20.28222 50.72641 Lubuskie Sieradz Sieradz
```

How to define Ggps points. I was using `over` function but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `raster::extract`

```
library(raster)
voiv <- getData("GADM", country = "POL", level = 1)
xy <- cbind(20.28222, 50.72641)

e <- extract(voiv[, c("NAME_0", "NAME_1")], xy)
e
#  point.ID poly.ID NAME_0         NAME_1
#1        1      13 Poland Swietokrzyskie
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using the revgeocode function from ggmap, but you need your own API key

```
library(ggmap)

ggmap::register_google(key = "your api key")


revgeocode(location = c(20.28222, 50.72641), output = c("address", "all"), force = FALSE, urlonly = FALSE, override_limit = FALSE)


"Mniszek 4, 28-366, Poland"
```

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates and names are in different slots. Extract the former using `coordinates`. After that you could `cbind` them together.

```
r <- cbind(gm[grep("^NAME", names(gm))], `colnames<-`(coordinates(gm), c("lng", "lat")))
```

Find Lubuskie in result:

```
head(r[r$NAME_1 %in% "Lubuskie", ])
#       NAME_0   NAME_1 NAME_2            NAME_3      lng      lat
# 41070 Poland Lubuskie Gorzów         Bogdaniec 15.09408 52.68379
# 41116 Poland Lubuskie Gorzów          Deszczno 15.29237 52.65471
# 40825 Poland Lubuskie Gorzów           Klodawa 15.26856 52.82939
# 41258 Poland Lubuskie Gorzów Kostrzyn Nad Odra 14.63813 52.61470
# 40855 Poland Lubuskie Gorzów          Lubiszyn 14.98341 52.79892
# 40950 Poland Lubuskie Gorzów            Santok 15.43891 52.74680
```